# Spray is rejecting my request for the wrong reason (405 but should be 400) when a query parameter on a PUT is the wrong type

Tags: scala, spray

With Spray 1.3.1, I defined a `Route` like this:

```
val route: Route = 
  pathPrefix("v1" / "myapi") {
    (path(Segment / Segment) & parameter("page".as[Int].?) & get) { (a, b, page) =>
      ...
    } ~
    (path(Segment / Segment) & entity(as[String]) & parameter("timer".as[Int].?) & put) { (a, b, body, timer) =>
      ...
    } ~
    (path(Segment / Segment) & delete) { (a, b) =>
      ...
    }
  }
```

Now, when I go to test for an error when using a bunch of letters for the query parameters which are being unmarshalled as `Int`s, I get what I expect from the `GET` request:

```
$ curl -v -1 -X GET http://127.0.0.1:1234/v1/myapi/foo/bar?page="lalala"
...
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...
'lalala' is not a valid 32-bit integer value
```

But when I try again for the `PUT`, this happens:

```
$ curl -v -1 -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8" -X PUT -d '{"items": ["stuff", "stuff", "stuff"]}' http://127.0.0.1:1234/v1/myapi/foo/bar?timer="lalala"
...
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
...
HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: GET, DELETE
```

What's the deal? I should add that if the number is formatted correctly it gets parsed and used just fine.

Comment: Although I can't tell why exactly the 'method not allowed' error is happening, I think your route should work if you either use nesting  instead of concatenating the routes (like in `put { path(Segment/Segment ... }`) or move the respective method keyword within your path matcher before the parameters directive.

Comment: @user3567830 Writing it as `(put & path(...) ...)` worked. Could you please write that up as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move the respective method directive within your path matcher before the parameters directive, for instance:

```
 (put & path(Segment / Segment) & entity(as[String]) & parameter("timer".as[Int].?)) { (a, b, body, timer) =>
      ...
  }
```

Alternatively, instead of the & operator, you could also use nesting to compose your routes:

```
val route: Route =
    pathPrefix("v1" / "myapi") {
      get {
        (path(Segment / Segment) & parameter("page".as[Int].?)) { (a, b, page) =>
          ...
        }
      } ~ put {
        (path(Segment / Segment) & entity(as[String]) & parameter("timer".as[Int].?)) { (a, b, body, timer) =>
          ...
        }
      } ~ delete {
        (path(Segment / Segment)) { (a, b) =>
          ...
        }
      }
    }
```